# Loss of connection to the HTML5 Web SQL after following url scheme

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, local-storage, web-sql

I am developing an application using HTML5 and Web SQL on Google Chrome. The
application calls an external app using custom URL scheme (e.g. skype://). 
When the user click on such URL (e.g. window.location.href='aaa://bbb'), the
JS browser engine breaks down and the database connection is lost. During
the debug, the database object returns 0 error code. Database size is small
- it cannot be the cause of the breakdown.

Did anyone come across a similar issue? How can I fix this? (the database
connection must not break when the user clicks on a custom URL such as
'skype://')

Will appreciate your advice!

Comment: Just a notice : you're aware that Web SQL as a standard is abandoned ?

Comment: At the initial stage, we needed the support of three platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) then it was decided to use the [Web SQL DB](http://caniuse.com/sql-storage) (PhoneGap). Unfortunaly [IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb) is currently supported only one of our platform (Windows - Google Chrome).

Comment: Hmm- for your click events, are you returning false on them? What about opening the URL in a new window? In theory - the new window won't even appear - I think. Anyway, give it a shot.

Comment: as Raymond said, could you invoke remote resource without setting window.location.href, of which browser must redirect to the new url? Return false or preventDefault will not take intended action, other than running click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Another new storage option is [SequelSphere](http://www.sequelsphere.com).

It is an HTML5/JavaScript Relational Database that support SQL.  It is it's own database engine, and stores its data in localStorage rather than using WebSQL.  As such, it works across all browsers, and won't be disrupted when the user clicks a custom URL scheme. This might meet your needs very well.